# Dpkg dh_install: copy files from the build directory rather than the debian/tmp dir?

Tags: debian, dpkg, packaging

Suppose I have a debian package housing as follows:

```
project_pkg/
  .git
  project_0.0-1/
     debian/
        install
        ...
     project (git submodule with tagged commit)
```

With the following install file:

```
// .../debian/install
#!/usr/bin/env bash
find $(pwd)/project/path/to/binaries -type f -executable -printf "$(pwd)/project/path/to/binaries/%f usr/bin\n"
```

And where the project has a `make` entrypoint such that `make -C project build` for example produces all the necessary files I would need to package.

The make/build component of the entire packaging process works right now.  However, ideally, I find all the necessary files I need to install from the install folder.

I have a solution for now, which would involve copying the binaries in the project to the `debian/tmp/` from either outside `/debian` or from `/debian/rules`.

But I could just as easily set the `dh_install` to fetch the files from the project, if there was some way to do so..

A) Is there a way to get `dh_install` to fetch files from the project,

B) Is simply running two `find` commands and copying the binaries to the `debian/tmp` dir the way to go?

C) Should I just hack it and prefix the `printf` in the install find command with `../..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `dh_install` takes paths relative to the current directory, which is generally the top-level directory of the package. In your case that’s `project_0.0-1`, so your `find` invocations should output `project/path/to/...`.
2. Yes, that would work too. I know I recommended `dh_install`, but the first rule of `debhelper` remains that it’s a tool at your service, and if you find it’s easier to skip it, you might as well do so:

   ```
   override_dh_install:
           install -d debian/package/usr/bin
           find project/path/to/binaries -type f -executable -exec install -t debian/package/usr/bin {} + \;
   ```
3. I don’t think that would work.

(In most cases I’d expect your main build to be capable of installing binaries to a given target, but that’s another discussion.)