# Why dh_auto_install and dh_install are not using same directory?

Tags: packaging, deb

I try to build a single package from source using *dpkg-buildpackage*.
At some point `dh_auto_install` is invoked and run `make install DESTDIR=/somewhere/debian/package-name`

Then `dh_install` is invoked but only search in `.` or `debian/tmp` but not in `debian/package-name` !

And I get something like:

```
dh_install: Cannot find (any matches for) "usr/include/*" (tried in ., debian/tmp)
```

How to make both of them use in the same dir ?

(There is no issue if I try to build multiple packages)
(compat 9)

Comment: Shall I use _dh_auto_install --destdir=debian/tmp_ or _dh_install --sourcedir=debian/package-name_ or tweak _rules_ or add un extra empty package or else ?

Comment: for the record _dh_auto_install --destdir=debian/tmp_ also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m guessing your source package builds a single binary package; *i.e.*, your `debian/control` has a single `Package:` stanza. In such situations, `dh_auto_install` installs files to `debian/package`, and the assumption then is that that is sufficient, *i.e.* all the files you need to install end up in the right place under `debian/package` once `dh_auto_install` completes.

`dh_install` is useful mostly for source packages building multiple binary packages: it takes files under `debian/tmp` or `.` and copies them to the appropriate target under `debian/packageX`.

In your case, since you’re trying to install `usr/include/*`, I suspect you don’t need `dh_install` at all — you should find the files you want to install ready and waiting in `debian/package/usr/include`. However, if you’re installing files under `usr/include`, you might be packaging a library, in which case you should change your `debian/control` file to create multiple binary packages (one for the library, one for the development files), and then `dh_auto_install` will install to `debian/tmp` and `dh_install` will work as you expect.

See also [Dpkg dh_install: copy files from the build directory rather than the debian/tmp dir?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/542305/86440)

Comment: Reason for single package is it's a header only library.

Comment: Ah right, that makes sense, so you might not need `dh_install` at all then.

Comment: Thanks @StephenKitt that helped me fix my header only package quickly :) A simple `override_dh_install:` with a blank line in the rules file, does the trick.